# TypeError: Object of type Restaurant is not JSON serializable!!! Please tell me I am writing tests for drf, I get such an error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class CreatePizzaTestt(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.restaurant = Restaurant.objects.create(name='Print', address='1')
        Restaurant.objects.create(name='Print12', address='1')
        self.valid = {
            'restaurant': self.restaurant,
            'pizza': 'Muffin',
            'cheese': 'Muffin',
            'dough': 'Pamerion',
            'ingredient': 'White'
        }

    def test_restaurant_create(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('create_pizza'), self.valid)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

The `data` parameter of `client.post` method needs to be a python dictionary or list with values that can be serializable, e.g. `str`, `bool`, `int`, `float`, ...

However, the value of field `restaurant` is an instance of `Restaurant`, which is not serializable.

## Solution

Change value of field `restaurant` to be `restautant.id`

```py
self.valid = {
    'restaurant': self.restaurant.id,
    ...
}
```